# How to load flex modules as list itemrenderers with moduleloader tag?

Tags: flex3, module, itemrenderer

I have a list compontent with an extrunal itemrenderer. My itemrender is a module that I would like to load in at runtime.

I have used the moduleloader tag but it doesn't display anthing. If i don't use the moduleloader tag but the `<modulename>` instead of `<productsView:menuBtn>` it displays the content.

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Application file with list component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
 layout="vertical"
 initialize="catagories.send();">

<mx:HTTPService id="catagories" url="data/products.xml"
            resultFormat="e4x"/>

<mx:XMLListCollection id="myXC"
        source="{catagories.lastResult.product}"/>

<mx:List id="r" dataProvider="{myXC}" 
     width="185" height="100%" 
     backgroundAlpha="0"
     paddingTop="0"
     paddingBottom="0"
     paddingLeft="0"
     paddingRight="0"
     borderStyle="none">
     <mx:itemRenderer>
      <mx:Component>
       <mx:ModuleLoader url="productsView/menuBtn.swf"/>
      </mx:Component>
     </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>
</mx:Application>
```

my module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
 layout="horizontal"
 width="185" 
    paddingLeft="3"
 paddingRight="3"
 paddingTop="3"
 paddingBottom="3"
 backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
 backgroundAlpha="0.8"
 borderStyle="solid">

 <mx:Image id="labelIcon" source="{data.icon}"/>
 <mx:Label id="catagory" text="{data.catagory}"/>
</mx:Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you cannot load several instances of a module. The way to get around this is by altering the url to make Flex think each call is unique.

Try replacing the ModuleLoader code with

`<mx:ModuleLoader url="{'module.swf?' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10)}"/>`